# Oauth2 token with non-standard prefix for scopes

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, nimbus-jose-jwt

The 3rd party Oauth2 resources server that I am required to use returns the scopes in the JWT token with a prefix of `scp` as in `"scp": "read_notifications.v1"`.  When spring security parses the JWT it returns an empty set of scopes.

Does anyone know of a way to customize the parsing of the token to include `scp` as an alias for `scope`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes [I know ways to customize the parsing of tokens](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials).

#### With Spring Boot Starters of mine

Sample for a reactive OAuth2 client

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.c4-soft.springaddons</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-addons-webflux-jwt-client</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.c4-soft.springaddons</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-addons-webflux-jwt-test</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.11</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
public class OAuth2SecurityConfig {
}
```

```yaml
scheme: http
gateway-uri: ${scheme}://localhost:${server.port}
origins: ${scheme}://localhost:4200
issuer: https://oidc.c4-soft.com/auth/realms/spring-addons
client-id: spring-addons
client-secret: change-me

server:
  port: 8888
  ssl:
    enabled: false

spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          c4-soft:
            issuer-uri: ${issuer}
        registration:
          c4-soft-authorization-code:
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            client-id: ${client-id}
            client-secret: ${client-secret}
            provider: c4-soft
            scope: openid,profile,email,offline_access,roles

com:
  c4-soft:
    springaddons:
      security:
        issuers:
        - location: ${issuer}
          authorities:
          - path: $.scp
        client:
          client-uri: ${gateway-uri}
          security-matchers: /**
          permit-all:
          - /login/**
          - /oauth2/**
          - /
          - /v3/api-docs/**
          - /actuator/health/readiness
          - /actuator/health/liveness
          - /.well-known/acme-challenge/**
          csrf: cookie-accessible-from-js
          back-channel-logout-enabled: true

---
scheme: https

server:
  ssl:
    enabled: true

spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: ssl
```

With `com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.issuers[].authorities[]` properties, you can configure an auto-wired authorities converter. Here, I just set `scp` as source for Spring Authorities, but you can also define a prefix (something like `ROLE_` or `SCOPE_`) and force to upper or lower case.

Browse the [samples](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples) and [tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials) for different use cases (servlets, resource servers, ...)

#### With Spring Boot "official" starters

The manual answers your question for:

- [servlets resource server](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-authorization-extraction)
- [reactive resource server](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html#webflux-oauth2resourceserver-jwt-authorization-extraction)
- [servlet clients](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/login/advanced.html#oauth2login-advanced-map-authorities)
- [reactive clients](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/oauth2/login/advanced.html#webflux-oauth2-login-advanced-map-authorities)

Comment: You're welcome, it didn't take me long to write: the OAuth2 chapter of Spring Security manual is in my favorite bookmarks (you should have it too when working with Spring and OAuth2). You might find useful tips in my tutorials too (first link), and should probably take 10 minutes to read main README: with "my" starters, what you need can be achieved with 0 Java conf (just a few properties).

Comment: The links to the Spring docs are for the resource server.  I am only using the client.  Specifically the R2dbcReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService that stores the credentials in a DBMS.  I'm reviewing your github to see if there is something that will help.

Comment: I added links for mapping authorities in client applications. I also edited the answer for a reactive client. The only reactive client in my samples and tutorials is the gateway module of the BFF tutorial.

Comment: Nice update!  I'm working through your samples to see if it resolves my specific situation.